# IPv6 Connector in server.xml is throwing exception on SipSessionImpl.setOutboundInterface

Tags: java, tomcat, sip, restcomm

I am using mss-4.0.21-apache-tomcat-8.0.26, which contains sip-servlets-impl-4.0.21.jar.

I am trying to setup an IPv6 address in the Connector in the server.xml, same as either of the below two examples below:

1)

```
<ipAddress = "2a02:ed0:1000:3031::1600"
protocol="org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipProtocolHandler"
signalingTransport="udp"/>
```

or

2)

```
<ipAddress = "[2a02:ed0:1000:3031::1600]"
protocol="org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipProtocolHandler"
signalingTransport="udp"/>
```

In both options, in the log, i see the following printout:

```
2016-06-19 12:43:45,838 DEBUG SipNetworkInterfaceManagerImpl Outbound Interface List :
2016-06-19 12:43:45,838 DEBUG SipNetworkInterfaceManagerImpl Outbound Interface : sip:[2a02:ed0:1000:3031:0:0:0:1600]:5070;transport=udp
2016-06-19 12:43:45,838 DEBUG SipNetworkInterfaceManagerImpl Outbound Interface : sip:[2a02:ed0:1000:3031:0:0:0:1600]:5061;transport=tcp
2016-06-19 12:43:45,838 DEBUG SipNetworkInterfaceManagerImpl Outbound Interface : sip:[2a02:ed0:1000:3031:0:0:0:1600]:5081;transport=tls
2016-06-19 12:43:45,839 DEBUG SipNetworkInterfaceManagerImpl Outbound Interface : sip:[2a02:ed0:1000:3031:0:0:0:1600]:5082;transport=ws
```

i am trying to run the following code lines, in order to use method setOutboundInterface:

1)

```
request.getSession().setOutboundInterface(new java.net.InetSocketAddress("[2a02:ed0:1000:3031:0:0:0:1600]", 5070));
```

or

2)

```
request.getSession().setOutboundInterface(new java.net.InetSocketAddress("2a02:ed0:1000:3031:0:0:0:1600", 5070));
```

but both are throwing the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Network interface for 2a02:ed0:1000:3031:0:0:0:1600:5070 not found
        at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipSessionImpl.setOutboundInterface(SipSessionImpl.java:1976)
        at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.message.MobicentsSipSessionFacade.setOutboundInterface(MobicentsSipSessionFacade.java:198)
        at com.ele.asnetiservices.signaling.sipengine.common.SipHelper.setIncomingOutboundInterface(SipHelper.java:603)
        at com.ele.asnetiservices.signaling.sipengine.core.machines.InitialFSM.initFromRequest(InitialFSM.java:560)
        at com.ele.asnetiservices.signaling.sipengine.core.machines.InitialFSM.init(InitialFSM.java:276)
        at com.ele.asnetiservices.signaling.sipengine.core.machines.InitialFSM.transition_11_1_guard(InitialFSM.java:836)
        at com.ele.asnetiservices.signaling.sipengine.core.machines.InitialFSM$35.invoke(InitialFSM.java:119)
        at org.echarts.TransitionTarget.evaluateGuard(TransitionTarget.java:51)
        at org.echarts.BasicTransitionTarget.satisfiesGuard(BasicTransitionTarget.java:43)
        at org.echarts.CompoundTransitionTarget.satisfiesGuard(CompoundTransitionTarget.java:38)
        at org.echarts.MachineMessagelessTransitions.getEnabledTransition(MachineMessagelessTransitions.java:108)
        at org.echarts.MachineMessagelessTransitions.getMaxEnabledTransition(MachineMessagelessTransitions.java:58)
        at org.echarts.TransitionMachine.resetMaxEnabledMessagelessTransition(TransitionMachine.java:696)
        at org.echarts.TransitionMachine.resetActiveTransitions(TransitionMachine.java:408)
        at org.echarts.TransitionMachine.resetActiveTransitions(TransitionMachine.java:286)
        at org.echarts.TransitionMachine.resetActiveTransitions(TransitionMachine.java:270)
        at org.echarts.TransitionMachine.runMessageTransitionSequence(TransitionMachine.java:1249)
        at org.echarts.TransitionMachine.run(TransitionMachine.java:1122)
        at org.echarts.servlet.sip.FeatureBox.advanceBoxMachine(FeatureBox.java:279)
        at org.echarts.servlet.sip.BoxPort.input(BoxPort.java:44)
        at org.echarts.servlet.sip.EChartsSipServlet.dispatchToFreeBox(EChartsSipServlet.java:552)
        at org.echarts.servlet.sip.EChartsSipServlet.doRequest(EChartsSipServlet.java:490)
        at com.ele.asnetiservices.signaling.sipengine.core.SipEngineServlet.doRequest(SipEngineServlet.java:398)
        at javax.servlet.sip.SipServlet.service(SipServlet.java:328)
        at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.MessageDispatcher.callServlet(MessageDispatcher.java:369)
        at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher$InitialDispatchTask.dispatch(InitialRequestDispatcher.java:746)
        at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.DispatchTask.dispatchAndHandleExceptions(DispatchTask.java:58)
        at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher.dispatchInsideContainer(InitialRequestDispatcher.java:451)
        at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher.dispatchMessage(InitialRequestDispatcher.java:306)
        at org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.SipApplicationDispatcherImpl.processRequest(SipApplicationDispatcherImpl.java:841)
        at gov.nist.javax.sip.EventScanner.deliverEvent(EventScanner.java:230)
        at gov.nist.javax.sip.SipProviderImpl.handleEvent(SipProviderImpl.java:185)
        at gov.nist.javax.sip.DialogFilter.processRequest(DialogFilter.java:1324)
        at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPServerTransactionImpl.processRequest(SIPServerTransactionImpl.java:807)
        at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel.processMessage(UDPMessageChannel.java:560)
        at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel.processIncomingDataPacket(UDPMessageChannel.java:512)
        at gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel.run(UDPMessageChannel.java:317)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Progress on this is tracked at https://github.com/RestComm/sip-servlets/issues/167